# NetBeans Java Debug: Variables not shown on hover

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I am using NetBeans version 8.1 and I've got an issue.

Suddenly while debugging Java projects, when I get to breakpoint I've lost feature of seeing variable information by hovering it.

How could I restore this feature?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The IDE might be getting hiccups, it happens sometimes when it is not able to load the components or due to some internal errors. 
Just do this:

- Save the project
- Restart the IDE
- Allow it to configure itself

If still, not then goto Netbeans helps sections.